# Android draw marker in runtime or at on LocationChange?

Tags: android

It is possible to draw markers in runtime or at onLocationChange event, not on Create event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "draw markers at runtime", you mean "add items to an `ItemizedOverlay` on a `MapView`", then, yes, you can update these whenever you want. Just call `populate()` again on your `ItemizedOverlay`. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkAsync/) that demonstrates loading overlay items asynchronously.